# Is it safe to use logrotate utility while logs are still being written by Apache?

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, logrotate

I have a server where Apache [mod_log_config](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html) mod is enabled. Using [rotatelogs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/programs/rotatelogs.html), it will produce a new log file once it reach 1GB :

```
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/log/logs 1G"
```

On the top of that, to save some disk space, a [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) script will compress logs files once they reach 100MB :

```
/var/log/logs_* {
    size 100M
    compress
    missingok
    notifempty
    rotate 7
    copytruncate
    maxage 7
}
```

It will produce the following result :

```
logs_20240216       //uncompressed at it did not reached 100MB yet
logs_20240216.1.gz
logs_20240216.2.gz
logs_20240216.3.gz
logs_20240216.4.gz
```

Is this safe to use *logrotate* to compress logs file while Apache can still potentially write data to them at that time ?

By safe I mean that neither Apache or *logrotate* will crash and the compressed files will be not be corrupted (eg: some logs entries are missing or it cannot be decompressed).

Comment: `copytruncate` isn't safe by itself, quote from the man page "Note that there is a very small time slice between copying the file and truncating it, so some logging data might be lost."

Comment: Then I guess one safe option would be to compress the files only after they have been rotated by rotatelogs itself (eg: they reached 1GB), possibly to another folder.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question: it isn't safe (at least using copy-truncate).
This is especially true if you write large amounts of data (as it increase chances of data loss).

The reason is that copy-truncate is a two step process : it first copy the file, then it truncates it. In between, it's possible that some data is appended to the file (this will be lost). Thanks to AlexD for pointing that out.

The solution I found is to no use `logrotate` utility and to only compress using `rotatelogs`

```
LogFile "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs -p '/path/to/compress.sh' /var/log/logs 1G"
```

Inside the `compress.sh` file :

```
#!/bin/bash
gzip "${2}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is safe, but you need to have the right logrotate config. And not rotate log files and let apache uses those logfiles, but instead let apache write to a new log file.
For example like this

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
    weekly
    missingok
    rotate 52
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 0640 root adm
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
    endscript
}
```

This reloads Apache2 after rotation to ensure that the new log files are used.